# is there a Human text syntax to HTML PHP parser?

Tags: php, parsing

i'm on a project to convert a github wiki to an offline documentation, So i need a php parser to convert these formats to HTML :

- Asciidoc
- Creole
- Markdown
- MediaWiki
- Org-Mode
- Pod
- RDoc
- Textile
- reStructuredText

now is there an all in one PHP parser for those syntax ?

Comment: This question should be on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 2):

[Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) may be the closest to a solution to your problem.  It's not in PHP, but surely you could call it via exec.

Answer (score 2):

> is there an all in one PHP parser for those syntax ?

All-in-one?  No.  Of course not.  Most of these markup languages are entirely unrelated to each other.  There's no reason anyone would want all of these at once.  You're going to have to find implementations for each.

There are pure-PHP processors for Creole, Markdown, MediaWiki, POD, Textile and reStructuredText.  I mean, seriously, MediaWiki is written *in* PHP.  Did you do **any** research on this, my friend?  Please, please fire up your search engine of choice and be enlightened.  `php <format> parser` / `php <format> processor` returns a plethora of information on how to process each of these in PHP.

Asciidoc looks to be a compiled program, but you should be able to shell out to it without a problem.

Org-Mode?  Isn't that an emacs thing?  No idea on how to extract that.

RDoc looks like a Ruby thing.  You should be able to just shell out to the native Ruby processor for it, that would be the most prudent thing.

Honestly, you'd probably just want to shell out to Perl to process POD as well, it's the native documentation format for Perl after all.

Comment: yes i did charles, i got the same result as kevine cline, thank you for the explanation